# Are there smaller packages for Standard rcl (resistor, inductance, capacitor) than 0402mm

Tags: pcb-design, hardware, pcb-assembly, component-selection, passive-components

I need to miniaturize a PCB as much as possible. Are there packages available on mouser for standard components like resistors (100k) or inductance (Up to 30nH) or Cap (Up to 100pF)?

Comment: I know there's 01005 packages, which probably correspond to metric 0201. No clue what component values are available in them, but I suspect you won't get a 30 nH inductor in that form factor.

Comment: You might be better to use the smallest parts you can get easily and using more PCB layers, buried & blind vias, and tighter spacing (subject to your PCBA house capabilities) to get higher densities. I'm not sure many places can actually mount 008004 parts reliably. HDI PCBs, on the other hand, are easily available, if a bit expensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is going to stick to 01005 available from common distributors like Digikey.

Note the caveats with the size:

- 01005 resistors can only handle ~1/32 W power. Sizes below 01005 are not commercially common -- digikey sells only one resistor with a smaller size, with a resistance of 0.02 ohms, and a minimum order quantity of 40000.
- 01005 capacitors can easily range well past 100 pF but may have lower voltage tolerance, tempco, etc. Below that, you have a [tiny selection](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/ceramic-capacitors/60?s=N4IgjCBcoCwGxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaI8cChlA7CDbTAKwMVP00ActnFPXEAF1CABwAuUEAGVxAJwCWAOwDmIAL6EAtACZEIFJHkBXAsTIhWIkBKkb16oA) of specialty caps.
- 01005 inductors are available; the largest I saw was 56 nH. Current handling is relatively limited. Below 01005/0402 metric, none are commercially listed.

Past 01005 there are very few options available. There are rare 008004 packages, as well as custom ones, but if you *really* need the miniaturization, you may need to consider integration on an IC (of course, scaling your design and passives to values achievable on a process that you can afford).

Comment: That's a surprisingly high inductance in such a small package. I bet the saturation current is tiny.

Comment: @nanofarad I was looking for a package that is even smaller than 0204 metric which is equivalent to 01005

Comment: @MarcoBobinger Beyond 0204 is a rarity -- you can see that [very few options are available](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/ceramic-capacitors/60?s=N4IgjCBcoCwGxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaI8cChlA7CDbTAKwMVP00ActnFPXEAF1CABwAuUEAGVxAJwCWAOwDmIAL6EAtACZEIFJHkBXAsTIhWIkBKkb16oA). Of course, it's possible to get custom parts, with the right budget and volume.

Comment: @nanofarad the link is broken, could you eventually provide a new link please?

Comment: @MarcoBobinger The link works for me on Chrome, including in an incognito window. It's nothing more than a digikey search for ceramic caps in every size smaller than 0.4mm*0.2mm. This [digikey short link](https://www.digikey.com/short/5q8mt0zw) might work, but if not, it shouldn't be too hard to manually enter the same search criteria.